# Decomposition of $K_0$ with Whitehead group

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence, k-theory

Let $Wh_0(G) ={K_0(\mathbb Z[G])}/{\mathbb Z}$, where $\mathbb Z[G]$ is the group ring of $G$ over $\mathbb Z$. Weibel states that the augmentation map $f: \mathbb Z[G] \to \mathbb Z$ induces the decomposition $K_0(\mathbb Z[G])\cong \mathbb Z \oplus Wh_0(G)$.

I see that the map induces a map $g: K_0(\mathbb Z[G]) \to K_0(\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z$. But I can't quite write down the short exact sequence he has in mind. What would it be?

Comment: Surely the s.e.s. is $0\to Wh_0(G)\to K_0(\Bbb Z[G])\to\Bbb Z\to 0$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How then do we define $Wh_0(G) \to K_0(\mathbb Z[G])$?

Comment: You write $Wh_0(G)=K_0(\Bbb Z[G])/\Bbb Z$. Therefore you must have a map $i:\Bbb Z\to K_0(\Bbb Z[G])$ in mind. The key to this problem is not writing down exact sequences but just checking whether $g\circ i$ is the identity on $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The fact that $g \circ i = id_{\mathbb Z}$ shows that $\mathbb Z$ is a summand, but I want the s.e.s. to know how $Wh_0(G)$ is a summand as well.